# PL/SQL: Assign a data type to a variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there anyway to do this? I want it to be done like this:

```
create or replace
package SOME_PACKAGE as
  filetype type is clob%type; --assign clob's filetype to a variable
end SOME_PACKAGE;
/

declare
  clb SOME_PACKAGE.filetype;
begin
  dbms_lob.writeappend(clb, 1, 's');
end;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
create or replace
package SOME_PACKAGE as
  subtype filetype is clob; --assign clob's filetype to a variable
end SOME_PACKAGE;
/
```

But why ??

Comment: Thanks. I am importing and editing a huge amount of pl/sql codes which declares variables with SOME_PCK.filetype as their datatype which of clob datatype. Rather than editing each instance, I just created the previous package with the filetype set to what I want.